# Is there any way to see how Google ranks my websites 'mobile friendliness'?

Tags: mobile, google-ranking

I noticed in the news that Google has tweaked their search engine to favour 'mobile friendly' websites, but don't notice anything different when I do a Google search.

Is there any way to see how Google ranks my site in this regard, or do I just have to guess?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a tool available from google that can measure your site's compliance with the new mobile requirements:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Answer (score 13):

If you’re referring to whether or not your site is mobile friendly according to Google then use the [mobile-friendly tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/).

You can verify whether it has kicked in by searching for your domain on a mobile device and looking for the “Mobile-friendly” tag in the SERP. If you recently updated your site it could take a few days for it to show up.

[image: Screenshot showing “Mobile-friendly” tag in search result for example.com]

If you want to find out how it has affected your mobile ranking display, then

1. Use the [Google Adwords Preview Tool](http://adwords.google.com/d/AdPreview/). Open it in two tabs and set one to mobile (see the image below) and leave the other one set to desktop. Then search for the same keyword in both tabs and check whether there is a difference in the results.

[image: Screenshot of Ad Preview tool, with “Mobile device with full browser” selected]

2. Search some keywords using your mobile phone and compare to the results on your desktop.

**Note: The full effect of this will probably not be evident for a few weeks. Here is a quote from the [Google Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2015/04/faqs-april-21st-mobile-friendly.html):**

> You won't be able to definitively determine whether your site’s rankings are impacted by the mobile-friendly update by April 22nd. While we begin rolling out the mobile-friendly update on April 21st, it’ll be a week or so before it makes its way to all pages in the index.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Webmaster Tools' mobile-friendly analysis, you may also want to use the [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) tool to check the *speed* of your site's mobile rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Google's tool measures only a few really basic things and mostly focuses on whether the content *fits on the screen or not*, a pretty crude measure.

A key point it misses is page weight. An RWD page with a 100MB image currently passes the Google mobile-friendly test. A genuinely mobile-friendly page should always endeavour to stay as light as possible to decrease load time and data costs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they introduce this algorithm to eliminate webpages that are not giving good user interface on mobile devices, but still they rank higher. Before they punish them, they already send notification to [Google Webmaster Tools - Mobile Usability](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-usability)

If webmaster fix the errors in Google Webmaster Tools by making mobile layout or responsive design, then they will rank same on Google, otherwise they will punished by this algorithm.

This algorithm is to punish website that is not mobile friendly, not for boosting traffic who have mobile friendly site, and they pass the mobile friendly test.

Just checkout this awesome [FAQ on Mobile Friendly algorithm](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2015/04/faqs-april-21st-mobile-friendly.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can check your Page Speed Test from Gt Metrix http://gtmetrix.com/

It will give you Two Types of report - one from Gtmetrix and another from Yslow(Yahoo Tool to check Website Speed).This can give you a rough idea of page size and other elements.
Google Speed Test https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

can be used to check mobile rendering from Google.You can also use WooRank to measure your website performance.